# HTML font rendering issue on non-retina display

Tags: html, css, font-face, retina-display, google-fonts

I am having trouble rendering Poppins on my site the way it renders on Google fonts demo site.

When using a non-retina display it renders "too thin", for example, the bars on the T are only 1px high, instead of 1.5px high when I look at the same text on font.google.com.

I like the way it looks on Google fonts much better. On my site the font looks "chopped" at the top but I cannot figure out what they are doing in their HTML to get a different rendering.

[This codepen](https://codepen.io/sarfata/pen/jOPJaOw) demonstrates the issue but beware: you need a non-retina display to see the issue!

[image: Codepen screenshot]

Code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 48px;

    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
  }

  main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 30% 40%;
    column-gap: 5%;
    align-items: center;
  }

  h2 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: normal;
    align-self: center;
  }

  a {
    color: #000;
  }

  small {
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  img:first-of-type {
    grid-row-end: span 2;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <h1>⚠️This issue is only visible on non-retina display!</h1>
  <main>
    <h2>
      Browser rendering
    </h2>
    <div>
      TITLE TEXT HERE IS 18<br />
      <small>^^^ T bars will be too thin on non-retina browser</small>
    </div>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/7LyzjJy.png" />

    <h2>
      Screenshot of Chrome on MacOS (broken)
    </h2>
    <div>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/2OZ0wv6.png" />
      <small>^^^ Notice how the T bar is too thin.</small>
    </div>

    <h2>
      Google Fonts<br />
      (screenshot of Bold 700 on <a href="https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Poppins?preview.text=HTML+TITLE+TEXT+HERE+IS+18&preview.text_type=custom&selection.family=Poppins:wght@400;700&sidebar.open">
        the demo page</a>)
    </h2>
    <div>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dgld0Jw.png" /><br />
      <small>^^^ Notice how the T bars are thicker</small>
    </div>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/pQPZ6Ch.png" />
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it seems to be redering fine to me https://imgur.com/QtDwjKm,
oops, Edit: I just noticed the date you probably solved the problem by now,
care to comment on what was the problem?

Comment: No the problem is not fixed. You need to look on a non-retina display to see the issue though and I have been told it works fine on Windows so this might be a mac-only issue but I have not confirmed this yet.

Comment: I'm on a macbook pro and the screenshot is from my second viewsonic HD display using chrome, still not sure if this is similar to the output you're seeing on your HD screen, for me it seems okay

Comment: Yes I agree. Your screenshot looks ok. Can you see the problem if you open the code pen I linked to in the question?

Comment: nope same https://imgur.com/d4HRgWq
have you set any flag in your browser (edited default browser settings)?
does the same issue appear on different browsers?

Comment: In your last screenshot you are seeing the problem I am talking about. I have edited your screenshot to measure the thickness of the bar of the T (https://imgur.com/a/qlEd9sQ) - The top two "TITLE" have thickness of 2 pixels which is incorrect (too thin). The correct thickness is exhibited in the third screenshot (3 pixels).

Comment: I have edited the codepen and the screenshot to be more explicit about what is broken. Sorry if it was not clear initially.

Comment: try adding `-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased; -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;`

Comment: Tried `-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased; -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;` - it does not help. Thanks @NickSurmanidze

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see your point,
 it seems that there are some issues with the latest version of this font, others have complained too.
now why it is rendered okay on google? it could be that the demo version google script is using isn't the same as the one on their fonts CDN though I'm not sure

---

**Solution:**

until they fix the issue, Use Webfont

[image]

same font same CSS as the one in your pen
except this is an [older version](https://github.com/itfoundry/Poppins/tree/v3.010a), you can host it on your own server
using something like webfont (I believe you know how to do that but in case you don't)
 [fontsquirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) makes the proceedure dead simple.

BTW this is on a mac and a separate HD screen

**Note:**
I noticed a tiny bit of spacing between the letters/words but nothing that 
can't be fixed with some CSS `letter-spacing` or `word-spacing`

Comment: I will try this and report back. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have tried the font from Adobe fontkit, the Poppins font on fontsquirrel - they did not work. Then I tried the ttf from [your link](https://github.com/itfoundry/Poppins/tree/v3.010a/resources/Poppins-hotfix) processed by fontsquirrel and now I get the rendering I expect. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First thing - since macOS Mojave, Apple has disabled font smoothing by default. This is hard to notice on Retina Displays, but [easy to notice on non-Retina](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/51132). Executing `defaults write -g CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled -bool NO` and logging out mostly fixes the problem. Without font smoothing text look a bit smaller.

The second problem seems to be in the way Google Fonts are working. When you type the preview text on Google Fonts demo page you are loading only characters you need for this given text - this is to save bandwidth as you are going to download about 18 styles of it.

However the font seems to be just a little bit different.

[image: Comparision]

1. Google Fonts embed
2. Poppins downloaded from Google Fonts, imported manually via @font-face
3. Font constructed by Google Fonts downloaded from the network page on developer tools

1 and 2 look identical. The difference in 3 is almost unnoticeable, except for letter T and E.

Please also note that on Google Fonts demo page text is rendered with `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` which usually makes the text seem a bit smaller, maybe this is why the generated font is a bit bigger.

This can be noticed if you have Poppins cached and change the font manually from generated one to real Poppins.

[image: Google Fonts default]
[image: Google Fonts real]

This is my take on this problem, but on the way to it, I also found that sometimes subpixel rendering was present.

Comment: Thanks for the well researched answer. I tried the `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` but it seems to be the default and I did not see any difference. I agree with your conclusion that the font sent by Google seems to be different from the one they offer on their CDN.